# GNUPLOT 5: conditional plotting with timefmt abscissa

Tags: time, conditional-statements, gnuplot

I am having hard time applying conditional plotting to data with timefmt abscissa using **gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 6**.

I am trying to plot the content of an ASCII file consisting in two columns:

```
2016-12-01    12
2017-01-01    1
2017-02-01    2
2017-03-01    3
2017-04-01    4
2017-05-01    5
2017-06-01    6
```

so I just issue:

```
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
set xdata time
p 'file.dat' u 1:2 w l, '' u 1:($1>strptime("%Y-%m-%d","2017-03-01")?$2:10) w p
```

I expect the plot to look like a line following the second column and a series of dots, following the line for the last three abscissas or marking the value 10 at the previous ones.

Actually, all the points are at 10. Do you have any clue about what is happening? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `timecolumn`.

```
p 'file.dat' u 1:2 w l, '' u 1:(timecolumn(1, "%Y-%m-%d")>strptime("%Y-%m-%d", "2017-03-01") ? column(2) : (10)) w p
```

[image]